# Filtrar elementos se elemento-filho dos mesmos tiver determinada classe

Tags: jquery, filter

O título da questão já é bem autoexplicativa. Eu estou tentando filtrar elementos (`div`) dependendo de se os elementos filhos deles tiver determinada(s) *classe*(s).

Encontrei o simples código abaixo que filtra muito bem, mas não exatamente do jeito que preciso - ele filtra as divs de acordo com as suas próprias classes, vejam:

```js
var $boxs = $("#divs > .tr");
var $btns = $(".btn").on("click", function() {

  var active = 
    $btns.removeClass("active")
      .filter(this)
      .addClass("active")
      .data("filter");

  $boxs
    .hide()
    .filter( "." + active )
    .fadeIn(450);

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #ecf0f1;
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
}
.btn {
  border: none;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px;
}

.active {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}
.tr {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="active btn" data-filter="tr">Show All</button>
<button class="btn" data-filter="a">Show A</button>
<button class="btn" data-filter="b">Show B</button>
<button class="btn" data-filter="c">Show C</button>
<button class="btn" data-filter="d">Show D</button>

<div id="divs">
<div class="tr"><div class="a b">A e B</div></div>
<div class="tr a">A</div>
<div class="tr b">B</div>
<div class="tr c a">C e A</div>
<div class="tr c">C</div>
<div class="tr d">D</div>
</div>
```

Como podem ver nas linhas

```
<div id="divs">
    <div class="tr"><div class="a b">A e B</div></div>
```

... então, quero que a div-mãe (`.tr`) seja filtrada dependendo das classes de suas filhas (`.a .b`), e não das dela mesma.

Alguma ideia?

Desde já sou grato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o método **[.has()](https://api.jquery.com/has/)**, que busca os elementos que possuem elementos filhos que casam com o seletor especificado.

A linha `.filter( "." + active )` busca as divs que possuem uma classe, então trocando para:

```
.filter( function(){ return $(this).hasClass(active) || $("." + active, this).length } )
```

Irá buscar também as divs que possuem filhos com a classe. O callback `function` retorna os elementos que possuem a classe (`.hasClass()`) ou que possuem algum elemento filho com a mesma classe. O código `$("." + active, this).length` conta os elementos filhos com a classe especificada e retorna 0 (se não existir) ou maior que 0 (se existir). Ou seja, uma das duas condições separadas pelo `||` deve ser true.

```js
var $boxs = $("#divs > .tr");
var $btns = $(".btn").on("click", function() {

  var active = 
    $btns.removeClass("active")
      .filter(this)
      .addClass("active")
      .data("filter");

  $boxs
    .hide()
    .filter( function(){ return $(this).hasClass(active) || $("." + active, this).length } )
    .fadeIn(450);

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #ecf0f1;
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
}
.btn {
  border: none;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px;
}

.active {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}
.tr {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="active btn" data-filter="tr">Show All</button>
<button class="btn" data-filter="a">Show A</button>
<button class="btn" data-filter="b">Show B</button>
<button class="btn" data-filter="c">Show C</button>
<button class="btn" data-filter="d">Show D</button>

<div id="divs">
<div class="tr"><div class="a b">A e B</div></div>
<div class="tr a">A</div>
<div class="tr b">B</div>
<div class="tr c a">C e A</div>
<div class="tr c">C</div>
<div class="tr d">D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Da forma que tem no momento apenas mostra os que tem descendentes com a classe escolhida, mas não os próprios elementos que tem a classe também. Ou seja quando clica no "Show A" deve mostrar o "A e B" assim como o "A" e o "C e A"

Comment: Mas isso vc não falou na pergunta

Comment: Na pergunta vc diz que quer filtrar pelos filhos e não pela div principal

Comment: Atenção que eu não sou o AP! O que interpretei pelo exemplo é que ele queria filtrar pelo próprio e pelos filhos, mas o melhor é mesmo deixar o AP se pronunciar.

Comment: Muito obrigado Sam, perfeito! O @Isac não é o autor da resposta, se é o que deu a entender.

Comment: O @Isac tem razão rsrs, foi assim mesmo que eu quis dizer. Mas marquei como correta porque nesse meio tempo achei uma solução alternativa. De qualquer forma, obrigado a ambos!!

Comment: @ThiagoSoubra Blz! Eu editei a resposta. Abs!